# Testing a RxJS Subject: subscribe method not getting called in the test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, angular-test

I have a private `Subject` **attributeNameSubject**. There is a **setAttributeName** method that passes a string value to the subject. We get reference to that subject using the **getAttributeName**. I am trying to test the above code, but I always get **false-positive**, i.e. the test passes but I get **test has no expectation** warning. Turns out it is not calling the subscribe method at all.

I am testing this code in Angular 7.

```
private readonly attributeNameSubject = new Subject<string>();

get getAttributeName(): Subject<string> {
  return this.attributeNameSubject;
}

setAttributeName(value: any) {
  this.getAttributeName.next(value.attributeName);
}

it('should set attribute name on valid input', () => {
  service = TestBed.get(AttributeService);

  service.setAttributeName('some random string');
  service.getAttributeName.subscribe((data: string) => {
    expect(data).toEqual('some random string');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. `setAttributeName` emits the value to the subscribers while `getAttributeName` listens to the observable. So when you call `setAttributeName`, `getAttributeName` emits a value but there is nothing subscribed to it. So you should first subscribe to `getAttributeName` and then call `setAttributeName` to emit the value.
2. The expectation will now be executed but the test will fail since the data is passed incorrectly. `getAttributeName` emits `value.attributeName` while you are just passing a string. You need to instead pass an object.

Here's the working test case.

```js
it('should set attribute name on valid input', () => {
    service = TestBed.get(AttributeService);

    service.getAttributeName.subscribe((data: string) => {
        expect(data).toEqual('some random string');
    });
    service.setAttributeName({ attributeName: 'some random string' });
});
```